# Calculating optimum shape of an air core solenoid magnet pair with given number of turns

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid, magnet

Consider a cylindrical \$N52\$ magnet with mass \$m_0\$ travelling in horizontal x-axis with initial velocity \$v_0\$ in \$-x\$ to \$+x\$ direction. It passes through an copper air core solenoid on its right side. The ends of the solenoid are connected to a measuring device that measures: current, voltage and the power as the magnet approaches, enters, travels through and exits the solenoid. Alternatively we can assume a small 80% efficient electric device connected to the solenoid. Let the cumulative power generated be denoted by \$P_1\$. Let the total number of turns in the solenoid be fixed to some chosen \$N\$.

**Query:** How do we calculate the parameters for the magnet and the coil such that for the given velocity \$v_0\$ maximum amount of kinetic energy is converted into power in the solenoid? And what is the maximum conversion efficiency we can achieve? Solenoid and device are fixed to the ground.

**For the magnet:** The length\$(l)\$ and diameter\$(d)\$ of the cylindrical magnet (their ratio \$(l/r)\$) (for a fixed mass \$m_0\$)

**For the solenoid:** The gauge or diameter \$d\$ of the wire, the 'shape' of the \$N\$ turn cylindrical solenoid. By shape we mean that all the \$N\$ turns can be in a single layer thus resulting in a long solenoid in one extreme case or a solenoid with \$t\$ turns in each layer and \$l\$ layers such that \$N=tl\$.

From Ohm's Law \$V = IR\$. The resistance is inversely proportion to the area of the cross section of wire, thus the larger diameter would lead to lesser resistance per unit length in a wire. Moreover the inner air core diameter should be as tight as possible w.r.t. the diameter\$(d)\$ of the magnet so that maximum number of field lines pass through the solenoid as the magnet passes through it.

But I don't know how to calculate these parameters. My background is not in EE so please take that into consideration.

Comment: What electromagnet do you refer to? A picture would be far, far better.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry i meant magnet. there is no electromagnet! an N52 magnet is travelling on x axis with a velocity v0 from left to right and passes though a solenoid that is also placed on same axis. thats the setup.

Comment: An [N52 example](https://www.stanfordmagnets.com/n52-grade-magnet-all-you-need-to-know.html) magnet will differ in properties between manufacturers. Do you ask for a general answer?

Comment: please assume a generic/standard N52 for calculations. A few percentage points here or there won't matter. the link you sent seems fine too. the reason I said N52 is they seem to be the strongest permanent magnets class.

Comment: For a given length of wire, and a given current, the coil geometry that gives the greatest magnetic field is known as a Brooks coil. Google it for the geometry.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Thank you (www.nessengr.com/techdata/brooks/brooks.html). I understand the shape. But this only partially helps. This is for a given current input. In our problem we need to figure the ratio of 2 things to maximize the power generated and to calculate it. It might well be possible (wild guessing here!) for optimal conversion the individual shapes might not be optimal but the combination is? And how do we calculate the conversion efficiency. That i am clueless about..

Comment: can someone please please help with this?

Comment: _"In our problem we need to figure the ratio of 2 things to maximize the power generated"_ - for what purpose?

Comment: @BruceAbbott The objective is for a given velocity \$v_0\$ and mass \$m_0\$ assuming we connect a device (say a led) that works at 80% efficiency i.e. it converts 80% of all input power to photons we need to maximize the power that is utilized to generate those photons from the kinetic energy. There must be a way to calculate this but I can't find any help!

Comment: _"There must be a way to calculate this"_ - there is a way, but it's not easy. By your definition energy induced in coil = kinetic energy removed from magnet. But the coil dimensions required depend on the magnetic field distribution around the magnet and its interaction with the coil, which is very hard to calculate from first principles. Usually it is done with FEMM https://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage . To extract all the kinetic energy you need the right amount of dynamic braking to just stop the magnet as it exits the coil, another tricky calculation.

Comment: @BruceAbbott sorry for the late reply. I understand the complications but I don't know th esoftware and my background is in CS so it might be somewhat steep learning curve. I understand for theoretical maximum we might need the s/w but is there no thumb rule at all?! we are willing to permit some percentage points of error. Something like the ratio for magnet length vs dia must be about x and the ratio of number of turns vs number of layers in electromagnet must be y ?

Comment: Rule of Thumb is defined as "a broadly accurate guide or  principle, based on **practice** rather than theory." . Problem is we don't have any practice to go by here. The closest application I can think of is the 'faraday flashlight' (https://faradaym.weebly.com/faradays-flashlight.html) which generally has a coil about the same length as the magnet and a little larger diameter. But these don't brake the magnet nearly enough to extract all the kinetic energy from it. In this situation I would build a device to test various coil dimensions and derive my 'rule of thumb' from it.